# Values of data in CSV does not match the values in the graph plotted

Tags: plot, time-series

I am trying to plot a time series data and my graph y-axis values (power) does not match my dataset in my CSV file.

In specific, my csv power data has values of only less than 100, but in the graph, the y-axis was set to 2000 as shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcpSO.jpg).

I don't know what did i wrote wrong. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The current year is 2017.

Did you just plot 2017 watts?

for example:

```
name,timestamp,power
Fred Smith,2017-02-25T00:00:00,70
Alice Smith,2017-02-25T00:00:00,78
Smith, John,2017-02-25T00:00:00,72
```